# Showing a label on right side on the table cell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I have a `UITableView` in which i am showing my custom cell, the problem is when the row is unselected it should show the text on the right side but its not showing, it is showing when i keep the row selected(long-press) i can see that there is a text label. my code is as below

Call from cellForRowAtIndex:

```
else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    return [self dataForSectionTwo:badgerAddAppointmentCellindexPath:indexPath];

(myCell *) dataForSectionTwo:(myCell *)badgerAddAppointmentCell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[myCell hideAllSubViews];
[myCell.textLabel setHidden:NO];
[myCell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE]];
[myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE]];
myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

[myCell.detailLblSectionTwoTrailing setConstant:0];
[myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo setHidden:NO];
myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
if(indexPath.section == 2)
{       
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        myCell.textLabel.text = @"Repeat";
        myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo.text = [self checkForRepeat];
    }
}
```

cellDetailLabelSectionTwo is UILabel.

Comment: try changing the color, to make sure its there, and check setSelected method of the cell

Comment: create custom cell ..

Comment: put full Method Code Of CellForAtIndexpath:

Comment: @RaheelSadiq the text is p[resent, that i am sure

Comment: are you using autolayout or autoresizing for your app

Comment: What the color of text in right side?

Comment: @Moseph it is custom cell, having a label on the right side.

Comment: @Nilesh Gimme a minute ill post the full code.

Comment: @KathiravanG the color is grey.

Comment: @uzairdhada show your constraints, and cell.m file

Comment: when you tap on cell show label dissect hide lebel

Comment: @uzairdhada I think you are setting some color in your SelSelected/SetHighlighted method in cell.m file, or you have set highlight color in your storyboard/xib file

Comment: @Nilesh plz check the full code, i have updated.

Comment: @RaheelSadiq actually there is nothing in the cell.m file, just the controller are synthesized, one method to hide all the controller, and method which is delegate - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange, which is for another use, thats all.

Comment: Post checkForRepeat method also

Comment: @KathiravanG the checkForRepeat method is just returning string, repeat, daily, weekly which i check working fine, this issues started after i updated my xcode to 7 and ios 9, before this code was working fine.

Comment: @uzairdhada try checking in your storyboard, according to the image above you have set text color to white, and selected color grey.

Comment: @RaheelSadiq the text color is grey, i checked.

Comment: can you change Color of "cellDetailLabelSectionTwo" label in the Method Like This :             myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo.textColor=[UIColor redColor];

Comment: @Nilesh i did changed the color to red and the issue is still the same, it not showing, but when i long press the row, i can see a red colored text written in red.

Comment: It's hidden under textLabel of Cell. when you remove textLabel. It shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hidden under textLabel Of cell

Debug View :

[image]

You are using the default label of UITableCell. Either you can do this.

```
[myCell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

OR
If you remove

```
myCell.textLabel.text = @"Repeat";  // This is the default label of Cell. You can add a custom label. Like the cellDetailLabelSectionTwo label.
```

It Shows up..

Comment: it worked very well, i was totally unknown of this debug view, surely this will help me further as there are many design issues. :-) , i wonder how and why this was working very well in ios 8 and xcode 6, the time when xcode 7 and ios 9 came my app is going crazy XD

Comment: Not came up with same issue before.  I mostly use custom labels, buttons, in cell. But whenever there is a UI related complex issue The 3D debug view is a great way to solve that. Thanks

Comment: yeah really the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     if(myCell == nil){
            myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    [myCell hideAllSubViews];
    [myCell.textLabel setHidden:NO];
    [myCell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE]];
    [myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE]];
    myCell.textLabel.text = @"Repeat";
            myCell.cellDetailLabelSectionTwo.text = @"Never";
}
}
```

Use this instead of the method you used.
Your Never is shown only for those which satisfy the **checkForRepeat** method. if you want it every time, then don't check it.

CELL is the cell identifier of your custom cell

Comment: thanks for your time, i tried this code was not working as i wanted, the way of irfan worked well.